# Jest clicking innerHTML: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jsdom, jestjs, grunt-jest

I'm trying to simulate click event of the DOM, but for some funny reason it just won't work.

Attaching the event to given a-element seems to be working, but clicking the element just keeps cursing at me.

Do I have something conceptually wrong in here?

```
    describe('Dummy', function test() {
    it('clicks the element', function it() {
        document.body.innerHTML = `
            <div>
                <input type="text">
                <a href="http://www.google.fi">This is a regular link</a>
                <button>Some text</button>
            </div>
        `;
        const element = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; // Get the 1st a-element
        element.addEventListener('click', e => {
            console.log('Clicked', e);
        });
        element.click(); // Invokes an error: TypeError: undefined is not a function
        expect(3).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

Here's a sample which works in browser, but not when running grunt jest:

```js
 document.body.innerHTML = '<div><input type="text"><a href="http://www.google.fi">This is a regular link</a><button>Some text</button></div>';
 element = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
 element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('clicked:', e)
 })
 element.click();
```

**Solution:**
Since jest-cli 0.4.19 does have such an ancient version of jsdom (~0.10.3), you need to use deprecated Javascript-methods, such as `.initEvent`. Proper event creations like `let evt = new MouseEvent('click');` won't work.

```
describe('Dummy', function test() {
    it('clicks the element', function it() {
        const evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initEvent('click', false, true);
        document.body.dispatchEvent(evt);
        document.body.innerHTML = '<div><input type="text"><a href="http://www.google.fi">This is a regular link</a><button>Some text</button></div>';

        const element = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        element.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('clicked!');
        });
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        expect(3).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

`

Comment: can you post demo in jsfiddle

Comment: I couldn't quite get it working in fiddle nor in this environment.

Comment: Looks like a bug in jsdom.

Comment: @Bergi Could you have any good pointers how to progress?? I can't really upgrade Jest, since it requires io.js-version of the node.

Currently I've:
"grunt-jest": "^0.1.3",
    "jest": "^0.1.40","jest-cli": "^0.4.19",

Comment: Hm, instead of using the `click()` method, trying [firing an event manually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) using [`.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

Comment: Still no win:S I tried to update the node to iojs and it broke grunt-jest.:(